# How can I use TCPDF functions in HTML2PDF, such as Cell, Line, etc?

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf, html2pdf

I was using FPDF until I added functionality that required HTML2PDF. Version 4 of HTML2PDF uses TCPDF, which has similar functions to FPDF. When I call those functions inside my class that extends HTML2PDF, I get nothing...

```
class PDF extends HTML2PDF
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->pdf->Cell(0,5.5, $text);
    }
}
```

How do I use the basic TCPDF functions and the WriteHTML ability of HTML2PDF?

Here is the function that calls test()

```
public function pdfAction()
{
    if (isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $memo = $this->getDbObjectById('Memo', $_GET['id']);
        $company_info = Config::get('Company');
        $pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', 'en', TRUE, 'UTF-8', array(15,10,20,15));
        $pdf->test();
        $html = '

<img src="images/itelogo.png" style="float:left;" />
<div align="right" style="overflow: hidden;"><h1 style="color: #00C;" >Memo</h1></div>
<hr />





'.$memo->text;
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $pdf->Output($memo->title.'.pdf'); exit;
    } else {
        $this->redirect("/memos");
    }
```

Comment: And you do call function `test()`? Show some more code!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?